# Django - Best strategy to enable users to order a list of objects

Tags: django

I have a the beginnings of a recipe app. Users add methods to a recipe one at a time. In a recipe app it is important that the methods appear in the correct order. I want the users to be able to order and re-order the stages of the methods until they are satisfied everything looks good but I have no idea:

A. How to allow the users to reorder methods

B. The best way to store the ordered methods

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=80)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    history = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='recipes/recipes')

class Method(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    method = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='recipes/methods', blank=True)
```

Here are the unordered methods that need ordering for a haggis recipe

[image: Unordered methods]

What strategies for allowing users to order this list are available to me?

Comment: The usual approach is to define an integer "weight" for a method and sort methods by their weights.

Comment: Where are users doing this editing? Within Django admin? or on the public side of your site?

Comment: Brandon: I'd like this to happen on the public side.

Comment: power: I'm trying this right now where users explicitly select 'Step 1, Step 2... etc. It gets unpleasant to edit if users need to add a forgotten method at the beginning of the list because the position of all the consequent methods needs to be adjusted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an ordered model: https://github.com/bfirsh/django-ordered-model
Then you can just: Method.up()/Method.down()